# Oracle: Can Weblogic 11G run PL/SQL code like App Server 10G?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, weblogic, application

This is probably a silly question, but I'm not an oracle admin so I'm not sure.  Our client currently runs a website written in PL/SQL and HTML on a Oracle 10G system.  As everything is moving in the direction of 11G the question has come up, will our current PL/SQL system keep working.

I guess the real question here is where does PL/SQL code execute?  I know the 11G database supports PL/SQL.  I'm just unsure about how Oracle is integrating what used to be Application Server into WebLogic Application Server.

Answer (score 2):

The PL/SQL runs in the database, and so any changes on the application server won't affect the actual execution of PL/SQL code. However, it may still impact on the final result, eg. how the application presents itself to the user, depending on how the application is built.

As for PL/SQL compatibility between Oracle Datababase 11G and 10G you will likely have to do minor modifications in the code. I believe Oracle is claiming backwards compatibility, but in my experience with previous releases there are always a few things that needs tweaking.

Comment: We're aware of the little issues that can come up from migrating the database so that shouldn't be a major problem.

As long as the new Weblogic app server will serve up our PL/SQL pages, we can make whatever other changes need be made.